# Create list from a vector according to lengths vector

Tags: r

Assume we have the following :

```
size_1=c(3,4,4,3,2,2)
as.numeric(row.names(strata(tmp, "Defect_type", size = c(3,4,4,3,2,2), method = "srswor")))
```

This output :

```
output=c(2, 3, 5, 24, 32, 36, 39, 41, 44, 50, 54, 61, 74, 80, 88, 93, 
102, 103)
```

I'm searching a way to obtain following list from `output` based on `size_1` :

```
list(c(2, 3, 5),c(24, 32, 36, 39),c(41, 44, 50, 54),c(61, 74, 80),c(88, 93),c(102, 103))
```

Thanks

Comment: `split(output, rep(seq_along(size_1), size_1))`

Comment: `relist(output, lapply(size_1, seq_len))`

Comment: Thank you , to be closed